# How do I allow users to see and filter a data list without allowing them to edit the sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 1300 lines. I want to enable users to see the list and be able to enter filter text, so only matching records will be displayed.

I can send the link to the sheet, but then when a user enters a filter, all other users will see it, and it will override their filter.

Comment: I made a change so that this can remain on-topic.  Asking for web application suggestions is outside of the scope, but there may be a way to do this using Google Spreadsheets natively.

Answer (score 5):

Users with view only access can use filter views. Tell about this to the users of your spreadsheets. Another solution is to use other tools like [Google Sites](https://www.google.com/sites/), o [Awesome Table](https://awesome-table.com).

From [Sort and filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en)

> #### Filters vs. filter views
>
> Both filters and filter views help you analyze a set of data in a
> spreadsheet.
>
> **Filters can be useful if:**
>
> 1. You want everyone viewing your spreadsheet to see a specific filter when they open it.
> 2. You want your data to stay sorted after using the filter.
>
> **Filter views can be useful if:**
>
> 1. You want to save multiple views.
> 2. You want to name your view.
> 3. You want others to be able to view the data differently. Since filter views need to be turned on by each person viewing a
>    spreadsheet, each person can view a different filter view at the same
>    time.
> 4. You want to share different filters with people. You can send different filter view links to different people so everyone will see
>    the most relevant information for them.
> 5. You want to make a copy or create another view with similar rules.
> 6. **You don't have edit access to a spreadsheet** and still want to filter or sort. In this case, a temporary filter view will be created.
>
> Note: You can import and export filters, but not filter views.