# How to let view-only users expand grouped rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am sharing my Google Sheet as "anyone with the link can view." The spreadsheet contains grouped rows. It appears that viewers cannot click the plus sign icons to show rows that were hidden by grouping them. How can the viewers expand the grouped rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I allow users to see and filter a data list without allowing them to edit the sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106050/88163)

Comment: The question suggests that the preferred solution would be to use plus signs to reveal grouped rows so the premise differs from that of [How do I allow users to see and filter a data list without allowing them to edit the sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106050). It is likely that there is no solution that would enable the use of plus signs in a view-only sheet. The "share as can edit, but protect sheets or ranges" workaround is probably better than the use of filter views because the question specifies row grouping. @Rubén

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users who have view-only access to a spreadsheet cannot modify it, and expanding rows counts as a modification, so it simply does not work.

One workaround is to share the spreadsheet as "anyone with link can *edit*", and protect individual *sheets* or *ranges* within the spreadsheet as required. If you are protecting full sheets, you will have to use the **Show warning only** option because otherwise the sheet will be completely view-only and row grouping cannot be used.

Another alternative is to use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) instead of row grouping to hide and show rows. This requires that some column in the dataset contains tags that let a filter view decide what to show and what not. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.